# A-tag Target=".." (New Window) Does Not Focus Window if Already Open

Tags: javascript, html

I noticed that if I already have a tab/window open from the first activation of an A-tag with Target, e.g.

```
<a href="file.pdf" target="user-guide">Help</a>
```

clicking the link subsequently merely reloads the tab but does not bring it to the forefront like it did the first time. Sure I can do some JS workarounds but I'd rather keep it simple. Is it default browser behavior to not re-focus an existing link open in another window?

Comment: At least FireFox has an option with which you can control whether an opened tab is focused or not.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#adef-target  section 16.3.2 -- it says that if a target for a given anchor is a set to a known frame, that link should load into that frame. Nothing in the spec says that the frame should be brought to the fore. As you say, there is the javascript option, but by default, the behavior is as you've noted.